# Whole bibliography is indented

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, align, indentation

this may be a simple question, but I can't find the way to configure all this properly.
My bibliography is moved to the right, it doesn't start at the beginning of the line:

[image]

My code is like that:

```
\documentclass[twoside,floatfix,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{marginparwidth=0.01cm,verbose,a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,left=30mm,right=20mm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[outercaption]{sidecap}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\def \dif {\mathrm{d}}
\def\beq{\begin{equation}}
\def\eeq{\end{equation}}
\def\beqa{\begin{eqnarray}}
\def\eeqa{\end{eqnarray}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textit{Epsilon}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textit{\thepage}}

\linespread{1.3}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}
  {\centering}
  {\raggedright}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\subsection}
  {\centering}
  {\raggedright}
  {}
  {}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\titlerule%
  \normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}[\titlerule]

 \titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}[\titlerule]


\makeindex
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}

\bibitem{Alpha} Alpha, Betha, Gamma (2019) State of the art of Delta

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

How can I make it start with the count right under the R of "References"?
It's curious because if I switch to *revtex4* instead of *article*, it is shown properly (with except to other incompatibilities).

Comment: Your example code is not compilable because the option of `\begin{thebibliography}` is missing. If I use `\begin{thebibliography}{1}` instead, the code becomes compilable but produces the following output (no indentation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb2pI.png

Comment: Off-topic: The instruction `\usepackage{fontenc}` is pointless; you should almost certainly replace it with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @leandriis Thank you! That resolves my question! (Can't add it as an answer though, it won't let me)

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example document yields a number of error messages pointing to the line after `\begin{thebibliography}`. The correct usage of his command is `\begin{thebibliography}{<width of widest label>}`, so you can see that the second option is missing in your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{11}
\bibitem{Alpha} Alpha, Betha, Gamma (2019) State of the art of Delta
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```